# JSDOM and pseudoclass :has()

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdom

I'm using NodeJS and [JSDOM](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom) for some scraping. I have:

```
const fragments = document.querySelectorAll("div[data-qa] a:has(span)");
```

This results in the message:

```
unknown pseudo-class selector ':has(span)'
```

Can JSDOM use pseudoclasses such as `:has()`?

Comment: According to [the MDM page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has)  for the :has pseudo class, it is still not supported by most browsers. I don't think you can use it with jsdom yet

Answer (score 0):

Currently there are several ways to use the pseudoclass `:has()` in [JSDOM](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom):

### Solution 1: use updated NWSAPI

To implement DOM Selectors API, JSDOM uses [NWSAPI](https://github.com/dperini/nwsapi), which needs to be updated to version >= 2.2.5, since this version [added basic support for `:has()`](https://github.com/dperini/nwsapi/commit/b8654a405e21a59fd95593e941484e422e7794d4).

However, currently there is still no support for more complex expressions `:has()` with nested subselectors.

### Solution 2: using polyfill

You can use [polyfill-pseudoclass-has](https://github.com/olegbarabanov/polyfill-pseudoclass-has), which can work not only with browsers, but also with JSDOM.

This *polyfill is slow* because it implements full compliance with the DOM API (especially NodeList), but it supports the use of complex expressions (according to [specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#has-pseudo)), for example: `div[data-qa] a:has(span):has(+ strong > span)`.

Example of polyfill injection into JSDOM ([sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/add-support-pseudoclass-has-within-jsdom-zskr2n?file=/index.mjs)):

```js
import { JSDOM } from 'jsdom';
import { addTo } from "polyfill-pseudoclass-has";

const customHtml = `
    <h1>Header Example</h1>
    <div data-qa>
        <p>
            <!-- CORRECT -->
            <a href="#!1"><span>Example 1</span></a>
            <strong><span>Custom text 1!</span></strong>
        </p>
        <p>
            <!-- CORRECT -->
            <a href="#!2"><span>Example 2</span></a>
            <strong><span>Custom text 2!</span></strong>
        </p>
        <p>
            <!-- INCORRECT: missing <span> inside <strong> -->
            <a href="#!3"><span>Example 3</span></a>
            <strong>Custom text 3!</strong>
        </p>
    </div>
`;

const {
  window: {document, Element, Document, DocumentFragment},
} = new JSDOM(customHtml);
addTo(Element, Document, DocumentFragment); // inject polyfill

const selector = 'div[data-qa] a:has(span):has(+ strong > span)';
const nodeList = document.querySelectorAll(selector);

console.log(nodeList.length); // => 2
```

The polyfill can be used directly without integration into the current API:

```js
import { JSDOM } from 'jsdom';
import { SelectorHandler } from "polyfill-pseudoclass-has";

const customHtml = `
  ...
`;

const { window: {document} } = new JSDOM(customHtml);
const selector = 'div[data-qa] a:has(span):has(+ strong > span)';
const selectorHandler = new SelectorHandler('div[data-qa] a:has(span):has(+ strong > span)');
const nodeList = selectorHandler.queryAll(document);
console.log(nodeList.length); // => 2
```

Answer (score 0):

As of [JSDOM 23.2.0](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/releases/tag/23.2.0), JSDOM has switched DOM selector API from NWSAPI to [@asamuzakjp/dom-selector](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@asamuzakjp/dom-selector), which according to the release notes, boasts better selector coverage but worse performance. `:has()` is one of the selectors that is covered by the new API.

Update: JSDOM 24.0.0 has reverted the selector API back to NWSAPI, citing performance concerns. If you need advanced selectors, 23.2.0 is the version to use for now.